# FTP Connection established...Connection timed out problem with all my sites and FTP programs?

Tags: 11.10, ftp, filezilla

Just few hours ago FileZilla was working fine. Then, suddenly I started to get this error:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.readtypechinese.com
Status: Connecting to 69.175.14.60:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

And it happens with all my sites:

```
Status: Resolving address of edasich.dreamhost.com
Status: Connecting to 173.236.223.223:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I'm using FileZilla 3.5.0 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Any suggestions to fix this? (I already tried Passive mode and it doesn't work).

[image]

**EDIT:**

Ocasionally, the log goes beyond the ...waiting for welcome message:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 DreamHost FTP Server
Command:    USER aleche23
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

But the connection gets timed out again.

Weird...I just realized that I have the same problems with other FTP programs too:

**gFTP:**

```
Looking up ftp.readtypechinese.com
Trying readtypechinese.com:21
Connected to readtypechinese.com:21
220 ProFTPD 1.3.2 Server (server) [69.175.14.60]
USER admin@readtypechinese.com
Connection to ftp.readtypechinese.com timed out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved changing an option (not really required) in the settings of the ftp connection. So in the site manager, choose the connection to your ftp, 
and on cryptation choose to Require explicit FTP on TLS.

When connecting it will ask about a certificate (accept it if you trust the source, that is the case, about your example), and the connection now will be working.

Comment: Great, just saved an hour of messing about